# Change ClusterRadius depending on current zoom Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to find a way to change the clustering radius depending on current zoom.

I want less clustering on higher zoom levels than on lower zoom levels, this is what I am trying to achieve, but it is not working very well, something is missing or done wrong...

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoom > 9) {
        return 20
    } else {
        return 80
    }
});

var mcg = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    chunkedLoading: true,
    maxClusterRadius: currentZoom,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `currentZoom` variable is declared within the inner scope of the event listener of your map zoomend event. You cannot access it outside that scope.
2. Changing the primitive value assigned to a variable will not make all other assignments update accordingly. However, the Leaflet.markercluster plugin API does offer a way to cover this use case: instead of providing a primitive value to the `maxClusterRadius` option, provide a function that returns the radius for a given map zoom level:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options

> You can also use a function that accepts the current map zoom and returns the maximum cluster radius in pixels.

Therefore in your case:

```js
L.markerClusterGroup({
    chunkedLoading: true,
    maxClusterRadius: function (mapZoom) {
        if (mapZoom > 9) {
            return 20;
        } else {
            return 80;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Excellent, then you can test out the best clustering options at different zoom levels. I did read the API document but could not figure out the correct way using it. TX